# Как прокинуть порты между контейнерами

Tags: docker, сеть, npm, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

У меня есть stage в gitlab-ci

```
test-dev:
  after_script:
    - docker stop browser_test
  stage: test
  image: docker:19.03.12
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - apk add --update npm
    - docker run --rm -d --name=browser_test -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome
    - npx mocha tests/js/screenshots-* --timeout 50000
    - npx playwright test tests/js/pw_*
    - php artisan test
    - docker stop browser_test
```

Но в данном случае, npx ссылается только на локальные порты по адресам 127.0.0.1:4444 и 0.0.0.0:7900

Но из-за того, что я использую docker in docker тесты падают ибо он не получает ответ, как мне правильн прокинуть порты между ними или связать их?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема сети между контейнерами gitlab-ci](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1483739/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-gitlab-ci)

Comment: Вопросы про разное решение разных проблем

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте запустить тест со следующей конфигурацией:

```
 test-dev:
      after_script:
        - docker stop browser_test
      stage: test
      image: docker:19.03.12
      services:
        - docker:19.03.12-dind
      variables:
        DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
      script:
        - apk add --update npm
        - docker run --rm -d --name=browser_test -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome
        - npx mocha tests/js/screenshots-* --timeout 50000
        - npx playwright test tests/js/pw_*
        - php artisan test
        - docker stop browser_test
```

Для того чтобы они (docker in docker) могли общаться и аутентифицироваться по сертификату, мы добавили `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"`, так же указали одинаковую версию (19.03.12).